# Custom terminal's bash commands on ubuntu

Tags: bash, terminal

I wanna make some custom commands for my terminal (i'm using Ubuntu).

I've already learned that i need to, for example, edit '.bash_aliases' file (in /home/your_user_name/), type 'source ~/.bash_aliases', and it should work then.

Well some things really works, like if i write (in '.bash_aliases') something like:

```
my_comm(){
            if [ "$1" = aaa ]; then
                    echo hi a
            fi

            if [ "$1" = bbb ]; then
                    echo hello b
            fi

            #echo this is a comment :]
            echo ending echo 
    }
```

then if i'll save file, type 'source ~/.bash_aliases', and run:

```
my_comm
```

it will print:

```
ending echo
```

and writing

```
my_comm bbb
```

will give:

```
hello b
ending echo
```

That's nice, but i want to know few more things, and i can't find them by google :(

---

### ------------------------------------------QUESTIONS----------------------------------------

(1)
how can i set a variable and then get the variable?

like:

```
var myVar = "some_dir"
cd /home/user/'myVar'/some_sub_dir/
```

?

(2)
i wanna make a function to shortcut a find/grep command that i use often:

```
find . -name "var_1" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l "var_2"
```

I did something like:

```
    ff(){
            find . -name '"$1"' -print0 | xargs -0 grep "$3" '"$2"'
    }
```

so, now executing:

```
ff views.py url -l
```

should give me:

```
find . -name 'views.py' -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l 'url'
```

but instead i recive:

```
grep: find . -name "$1" -print0
: There is no such file or directory
```

help pls :)

Comment: You've got an extra set of quotes in there. I think if you just do `'$1'` instead of `'"$1"'` it should work.

Comment: and as for #1, you do it the same way you did it before-- `cd /home/user/$myVar/some_sub_dir/`

Comment: @ Collen (#1) doing " var myVar = "ttt" " and then "echo $myVar" gives me " No command 'var' found, but there are 18 similar ones /n var: command not found"

...so $myVar is probably a way to GET variable, but how to SET it ?

Comment: `'$1'` won't work because expansions don't happen in single quotes. Use just `"$1"`.

Comment: and the thing with just deleting ' worked - thx ^^

Answer (score 2):

> (1) how can i set a variable and then get the variable?

Like this:

```
myVar="/long/name/may have/a space/"
....
cd /home/user/"$myVar"/someSubDir.
```

Double quotes don't prevent variable substitution (unlike single quotes).

> (2) i wanna make a function to shortcut a find/grep command that i use
>   often:

```
find . -name '"$1"' -print0 | xargs -0 grep "$3" '"$2"'
```

You achieve nothing useful with multiple kind of quotes here; actually you prevent `$1` and `$2` from being substituted and that breaks your function. Try this:

```
find . -name "$1" -print0 | xargs -0 grep "$3" "$2"
```

Comment: (2) works :)         but @ (1) - doing ' myVar = "ttt" ' gives me 'myVar: command not found'

Comment: @pbialy *Don't add spaces for aesthetic reasons if you don't know whether it's harmless*. Try `myVar="ttt"`. NO WHITESPACE.

Comment: wow, never thought that spaces may ruin something :P Works now, thx :)

Answer (score 0):

You can even using `alias` keyword for single instructions or use `function` keyword and combine couple of instructions in one. you can have a look at [this](http://sagarsakre.blogspot.in/2012/11/bashrc.html)